# Is QStandardItemModel::removeRows() recursive?

Tags: qt, qt5, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

When calling `removeRows()` on `QStandardItemModel` with tree structure does this free the memory for all the children `QStandartItem`s recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is QStandardItemModel::removeRows() recursive?

No. It can't be since a model isn't a tree of models.

> does this free the memory for all the children `QStandartItem`s recursively?

Yes, but this has little to do with `removeRows()`. The `~QStandardItem()` destructor disposes of the children. So any method that destroys a `QStandardItem` will also destroy and dispose of the children. Nothing will leak.